# Responsive div inside responsive image

Tags: html, css

i want Responsive div inside responsive image as below
[image]

any help would be appreciated.
i am not good at css:(

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: My code is not workable.. any other demo code something like this would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ey9ykhwd/3/

use percentage for placing the content `div` parent should be positioned `relative`

```
.content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 68.7%;
    height: 67.6%;
    background: Red;
    left: 15%;
    top: 11%;
}
```

```css
.cont {
  position: relative;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 68.7%;
  height: 67.6%;
  background: Red;
  left: 15%;
  top: 11%;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <img src="http://northwestpassageapp.com/wp-content/themes/relish_theme/img/ipad_border.png" />
  <div class="content">content here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If someone wants to do this without it been responsive it can be done like this.

Make the screen a background image and then use a relative positioned iframe.
i added a YouTube iframe to the screen in the demo.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ecwydkec/7/)

```
        .outer {
    background-image: url('http://northwestpassageapp.com/wp-content/themes/relish_theme/img/ipad_border.png');
    width:800px;
    height:596px;
}
.inner {
    position: relative;
    background-color:;
    left: 120px;
    top: 68px;
    width:550px;
    height:405px;
}
```

............

```
<div class="outer"><iframe class="inner"></iframe>
```

you could even use a 2 or 3px border-radius to match the image.

Comment: Thanks! this is use full

Comment: @Abbas Galiyakot Great :)